# Setting a FedEx API response timeout

Tags: api, fedex

I’m trying to set a response timeout for the FedEx shipping rate service but I’m not sure I’m doing the correct thing. What should I do to make sure the system doesn’t spend an eternity waiting for a response?

This is what I would do with native PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('connection_timeout'=>'2'));
```

And this is what I’m doing with Magento 2.3:

```
$client = $this->soapClientFactory->create($wsdl, ['trace' => $trace, 'connection_timeout' => '2']);
```

This is in `/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php::_createSoapClient()`

The problem is that I don't know if that is going to work.

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for best possible solution for the similar scenarios like If FedEx API down then how can we handle it on Magneto system? Currently on checkout page customer not able to place order and continue spinner loading...